# Add new FileServer locations after startup (edit middleware after startup)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, kestrel-http-server

My web application needs to let an admin user add and remove served folders from a .net core 2 app. I have found a way to provide a list of served folders, but I can't find a way to dynamically add or remove them once the app has been configured.

How do I re-run the configure function from within the application? Alternatively, how do I add or remove `UseFileServer()` configurations within an already-running service?

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseMvc();

        //get these dynamically from the database
        var locations = new Dictionary<string, string>{
            {@"C:\folder1", "/folder1"},
            {@"D:\folder2", "/folder2"}
        };
        foreach (var kvp in locations)
        {
            app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions()
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                    kvp.Key
                ),
                RequestPath = new PathString(kvp.Value),
                EnableDirectoryBrowsing = true
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using .net core 2.0.0-preview2-final.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to dynamically inject the FileServer middleware based on your settings.

There is an example project on Microsoft's Chris Ross' Github: https://github.com/Tratcher/MiddlewareInjector/tree/master/MiddlewareInjector

You'll have to add the `MiddlewareInjectorOptions`, `MiddlewareInjectorMiddleware` and `MiddlewareInjectorExtensions` classes from the aforementioned repo to your project.

Then, in your Startup class, register the `MiddlewareInjectorOptions` as a singleton (so it's available throughout your application) and use the MiddlewareInjector:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<MiddlewareInjectorOptions>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

        var injectorOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<MiddlewareInjectorOptions>();
        app.UseMiddlewareInjector(injectorOptions);
        app.UseWelcomePage();
    }
}
```

Then, inject the MiddlewareInjectorOptions wherever you want and configure the middleware dynamically, like this:

```
public class FileServerConfigurator
{
    private readonly MiddlewareInjectorOptions middlewareInjectorOptions;

    public FileServerConfigurator(MiddlewareInjectorOptions middlewareInjectorOptions)
    {
        this.middlewareInjectorOptions = middlewareInjectorOptions;
    }

    public void SetPath(string requestPath, string physicalPath)
    {
        var fileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(physicalPath);

        middlewareInjectorOptions.InjectMiddleware(app =>
        {
            app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions
            {
                RequestPath = requestPath,
                FileProvider = fileProvider,
                EnableDirectoryBrowsing = true
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Note that this MiddlewareInjector can inject just a single middleware, so your code should call `UseFileServer()` for each path you want to serve.

I've created a Gist with the required code: https://gist.github.com/michaldudak/4eb6b0b26405543cff4c4f01a51ea869

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. I need to register new UseFileServer locations AFTER startup has completed. I tested it, and once the app is running, any new app.UseFileServer calls just do nothing.

Comment: My solution should work, then. Since you have a singleton MiddlewareInjectorOptions, you can use it whenever you want (just get it from the service container). I tested it myself a while ago and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: Please take a look at the Gist I just added - At first, there is no file server functionality. Only when you go to /enable-file-server URL, you'll be able to access the contents of C and D drives by going to /c and /d URLs, respectively.

Comment: I must have done something wrong when I tried it the first time. That Gist helped a lot too. This is working perfectly now. Thanks! And kudos for an awesome solution!

Comment: I'm glad I could help :) By the way, would you mind changing the title to something like "How to modify middleware after startup?" - I guess this way it will be more discoverable and may help others as well.

Comment: @MichałDudak I'm trying to do something similar, but is there a way to remove middleware? For example, I would want to remove an external authentication provider that was configured in Startup.cs.

Comment: @Evan, you can wrap the auth middleware in a `MapWhen` method (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware?tabs=aspnetcore2x#use-run-and-map) that would check if the middleware need to be run. So you won't remove but rather disable the unwanted middleware.